# android TableLayout with LinearLayout as cells - layout_margin is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I have TableLayout. As each cell in Table Layout I have LinearLayout with few elements inside a nice border.

LinearLayout definition:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="?border_empty"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
```

Unfortunately layout_marginLeft and layout_marginBottom seems to be ignored. :-( I've even tried to set very high values ex. 15 dp. How to set more space between cells (I would prefer to set it on left and on bottom if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question yesterday but I wanted to wait until today to answer, because now I'm facing exactly the same issue.

I've tried using this (being `fila` my `TableRow`):

```
final TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
trParams.setMargins(10, 5, 10, 5);
fila.setLayoutParams(trParams);
```

But as you comment, both left and right margins seem to be ignored. I finally managed it through the `TextView` itself, this way (being `tv` my `TextView`):

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
lp.rightMargin = 10;
lp.leftMargin = 10;
```

This seems to work perfectly.

Comment: In my situation I inflate each cell as LinearLayout. When I execute getLayoutParams() I receive null (for this inflated layout). And then of course calling anything with null (lp.rightMargin) causes NullPointerException.... :((( However thanks for help and I bellieve your remarks will be useful for someone else having just pure TextView as cell.

Comment: I've just tried inflating a LinearLayout and using the same procedure it worked, not null pointer exception here. If you're still stuck, update your question with your try.